# If you took 18 cards at random from a 54 card deck (jokers included), what is the probability you get 4 of the same card?

Tags: probability, card-games

Question is pretty self explanatory, I'm just not sure if I'm right. My brain isn't functioning and I want to sleep.

Heres the full question in a tiny bit more detail;

Suppose you took 18 cards at random from a 54-card deck with both jokers included and without replacement. (You could also think of it as taking 18 cards at once randomly) What is the chance you get 4 of the same card? e.g. 4 twos, 4 kings, whatever.

Edit: After reading some comments, the suggested question is not what I want. About the jokers, if you are to draw a joker in your 18 cards there is no way it would count to 4 of the same card because there are only 2 jokers. 4 of one card is not 4 of the same suite, its 4 of the same rank. As mentioned earlier, an example would be 4 queens. I am also asking for the probability you get at least one set of 4 of a rank. So if you get 4 queens and 4 kings, the 2nd set of 4 would be a bonus. Hopefully this clarifies!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [a deck of cards has 54 cards...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2923450/a-deck-of-cards-has-54-cards)

Comment: This is a good case for inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: That question has a very different type of answer. @JitendraSingh

Comment: Do you want exactly one $4$ of a kind, or is more than one allowed?

Comment: Are jokers wild?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews that was for refrence maybe if he/she tries that way he can solve it

Comment: Yeah, but that way won’t work. @JitendraSingh

Comment: @ThomasAndrews lets see if OP gets help from duplicate or else I will retract my vote

Comment: is it "at least one 4 of a kind" or "only one 4 of a kind"?